# PHP imagecreatefromgif() always returns false

Tags: php, image, fpdf

I am using FPDF to generate PDF with and getting following error

```
    FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file
```

My earlier guess was there was something wrong with my GIF image, now i am validating my image with PHP function

```
image_type_to_extension()
```

Which returns gif.

So i don't know why

```
imagecreatefromgif()
```

is returning false, causing FPDF error.

Comment: Always, for every image?

Answer (score 0):

The function imagecreatefromgif() require a path of image as 
imagecreatefromgif("/var/www/image.gif");

Are you send the full path?

Try

```
if(file_exists($fullPath))
{
 $image = imagecreatefromgif($fullPath));
}
else
  die("Image Not found");
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the complete source file of a short program that illustrates the problem. That way one of us might change the path name and run it to see if it works.

By the way, an absolute path name won't work if the PHP is being executed by the HTTP server. For that, the image must be in a path within the website.

Comment: I've gotten this to work, but the absolute path was to a path within the web directory...speeds things up a lot if you use absolute paths instead of going over http(s)